# Xcode 7 does not symbolicate TestFlight crash report

Tags: crash, xcode7, testflight, symbolicatecrash

I am trying to use the new Xcode 7 feature that shows crash report directly into Xcode.

It is working well with my AppStore live version. But when trying to open crash report from my latest TestFlight build, it does not symbolicate, so I can't find the method name of the given crash.

Any clue on how to solve this ?

Thank you

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. Out of curiosity, do you have Bitcode enabled for your builds?

Comment: No, I don't. And you ?

Comment: I do have Bitcode embedded — I thought that might have been the culprit. Guess not!

Comment: I'm also in this same situation. Any luck?

Comment: Crappy iTunesConnect/Xcode. Same here. Bitcode enabled.

Comment: And another victim... Same here.