# Crash files not symbolicated

Tags: xcode, xcode7, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

The crash files for my most recent (in production) app do not have symbols and I can't make any of the manual symbolication processes work. Older versions of the app that some users are still running seem to be symbolicated fine.

I have verified Xcode has the archive:

```
1) Xcode > Organizer > Archives
2) Select archive and check version matches crash
3) Right-click > Show in Finder
4) right-click .xcarchive > Show package contents

Result:
the .dSYM file exists in 'dSYMs' directory
the .app  file exists in 'Products/Applications' directory
```

iTunesConnect includes symbols, so AFAIK the archive was built and uploaded correctly. Note that a link to "Download dSym" does **NOT** exist as [some other posts indicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549565/5135551).

```
1) My Apps > select app > Activity > All Builds
2) Select version that matches crash
3) General Information = Yes
```

I have tried to force XCode to symbolicate by dragging the crash log onto an existing device, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33765226/5135551) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25927122/5135551)

No luck using the `symbolicatecrash` utility either as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30431450/5135551)

Any idea why this wouldn't be working with Xcode 7.3.1?

**Update:**

When we upload to iTunes Connect, we have ensured the checkbox to include the dSYM is checked. BuildDetails for the build shows "Includes Symbols = YES", but there is no link to download the dSYM. If I try to download it from Xcode, it says it is missing. Any idea why?

**Update - Proved the crash UUID matches my dSYM**

I found the following post [How to solve symbolication problems](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems) very helpful to prove my crash UUID matches the UUID for the archive. They match, so I already do have the correct archive on my machine for the crash that is not being symbolized.

```
Find the UUID in the crash report
    - line just after "Binary Images" 
    - 0x100078000 - 0x1006ebfff MyApp arm64  <381e625bf2cc3703b0c76c723155c931>

    UUID = 381e625bf2cc3703b0c76c723155c931 for the crash file


Find the UUID in the app binary
    - Show Package Contents: MyApp-version.xcarchive/Products/Applications
    - run: dwarfdump --uuid MyApp.app/MyApp

    Result:
    UUID: 381E625B-F2CC-3703-B0C7-6C723155C931 (arm64) MyApp.app/MyApp

    UUID matches, just formatted to upper case with separators
    Proves the .app file matches the crash file

Find the UUID of the dSYM
    - Show Package Contents: MyApp-version.xcarchive/dSYMs
    - run: dwarfdump --uuid MyApp.app.dSYM

    Result:
    UUID: 381E625B-F2CC-3703-B0C7-6C723155C931 (arm64) MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp

    UUID matches - proves the dSYM file matches the crash file
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something went wrong when you uploaded your binary because a link to download the dSYMs should exist under `My Apps > select app > Activity > All Builds > select version > Build Details > Includes Symbols`.

You should bump your build number and upload another binary.  If you still don't see a `Download dSYM` link, please update your question.

**Update** See update below - This is appears to only be correct for apps uploaded with bitcode.

Comment: In iTunesConnect, all of the builds have "Includes Symbols = Yes", but there is no link to download the dSYM file. We have a very recent build where we carefully ensured the checkbox was checked to upload the dSYM.

Comment: Is it possible that the Download dSYM link in iTunes Connect will only be available if your app is compiled with bitcode, in which case Apple will recompile it? Our app is not using bitcode.

Comment: @JimLeask I went back and checked old Apps that were pre-bitcode and they didn't include a download link.  So you may be correct in that the download only appears when bitcode compliation is enabled.

Comment: After speaking with Apple and a small reference in the [App Distribution Guild - Viewing and Importing Crashes in the Devices Window](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html) it seems that the `Download dSYMs` button is only used if you include bitcode in your app.